# How to update MongoDB collection field using another field using MongoTemplate in spring-boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I need a field value to be updated using another field using the mongo template in spring-boot. I am aware of how this can be done using MongoDB queries. But could not figure out a way of doing this using `MongoTemplate` from the database level without loading the data to the memory.

I am searching for something like this. The `value1` is in the collection and it needs to be updated from a value from a nested array (`menu`) and 0th index contains the value always.

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("price").is(0));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("price", "$menu[0].sellingPrice");

    mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, CollectionName);
```